# How do I load dynamic image assets into adobe air

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder, swc

The app I'm working on displays four random images at one point. These four images come from a set of fifty images. If this was a standard Flex project I would just set the img.source property:

```
this.img1.source ="../assets/img/"+randomname+".png";`
```

This isn't working though, I'm getting a broken image. One other way to go about it is to load the image with a urlLoader, which is also not loading the image (unsurprisingly, given that it's a local asset)

```
loader = new Loader();
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("../assets/img/"+randomname+".png");
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
loader.load(urlReq)
```

So this isn't working either, I'm thinking of loading all of the images into a swc and then linking the swc to the project. This is obviously not great because then all the assets are loaded into memory at runtime. Is there another way of doing this?

I'm hoping that I'm missing something really simple.

If the .swc solution is the best one, can someone point me in the right direction? I forget how that whole business works, as it's been a couple of years since I've worked with Flex/Flash.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `URLLoader` will load a file off the file system. You probably have the incorrect URL for your image. Where is the "assets" folder in relation to your project's "src" folder?

Comment: The 'assets' folder is on the same level as the 'src' folder. I've tried `URLLoader` with both "../assets/img" and "assets/img" as the beginning of the file path. I get a `Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.` error

Comment: Are you running this from Flash Builder? Is the assets folder getting copied into the bin-debug folder?

Answer (score 1):

You should add your asset directories as "source" directories.

Then you should be aware of the fact that the contents of the asset directories will be copied to the root of your application.  So when you have the image "assets/interface/bg.png" you should load it using new URLRequest("interface/bg.png").

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("assets/img/"+randomname+".png");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply michael. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. The 'assets' and 'src' folders are on the same level, and both "assets/img" and "../assets/img" as paramaters to `URLRequest` give a `Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.` error, which is why I thought that perhaps Air can't load local files (straightforwardly, at least). Any ideas?

Comment: I can get the file, but my assets folder is under the src folder.  Or you can try type the full path, eg. "c:/"+ the path to your project +"/assets/img/"+randomname+".png". "the path to your project" is something similar to "users/username/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/your project name" in window environment.